# Call to undefined function App\Http\Middleware\str_plural()

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-6

I am making a user ban function for my application. However, Laravel 6 is showing undefined `function str_plural()`. How can I fix this?

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->banned_at && now()->lessThan(auth()->user()->banned_at)) {
        $banned_days = now()->diffInDays(auth()->user()->banned_at);
        auth()->logout();

        if ($banned_days > 14) {
            $message = 'Your account has been suspended. Please contact administrator.';
        } else {
            $message = 'Your account has been suspended for '.$banned_days.' '.str_plural('day',
                    $banned_days).'. Please contact administrator.';
        }
        return redirect()->route('login')->withMessage($message);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

Str::plural()
```

for more info you can read [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-str-plural)